# Unknown provider error in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While running the following code the error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ItemsProvider <- Items" occurs.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="ShoppingController">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{items.title}}</td>
        <td>{{items.price}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript code :

```
var angModule = angular.module('ShoppingModule',[]);
angModule.factory('Items', function() {
    var items = {};
    items.query = function() {
        return [{title :'JW',price:100}];
    }
        return items;

}) ;
function ShoppingController($scope, Items) {
    $scope.items = Items.query();
}
```

How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory method needs to return the object that will be injected. With the code above, it isn't returning anything. Should be:

```
var angModule = angular.module('ShoppingModule',[]);
angModule.factory('Items', function() {
    var items = {};
    items.query = function() {
        return [{title :'JW',price:100}];
    }

    return items;// <----- Add this
});
function ShoppingController($scope, Items) {
    $scope.items = Items.query();
}
```

Comment: Do you have ng-app in your HTML? If there's no other modules, it'll need to be `ng-app="ShoppingModule"`, so that the `ShoppingModule` gets loaded. A fiddle or plunker would also be helpful.

Comment: @Cashew..Your are supposed to mention what are those few changes.